# Profile pictures

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

Random question, I log in with my Google account.  Is there some sort of mechanism that will use my picture from Google (or Google +) as my account image on sp.se?  I don't really want to create an account on a separate web site for the sole purpose of having a picture to assocaite with my account.

Comment: You mean [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/)? If you set it up there then it is used everywhere... works on most wordpress blogs too.

Comment: Correct, I don't want a gravatar account for the sole purpose of a profile picture when other accounts that you can log into the site with, store a profile photo as well.

Comment: You may get a more definitive answer on SE meta; since this is more core SE related.

Comment: That's true, I'll ask there.

Comment: @PirateEric If you get a useful answer, could you link to it here, please? Questions with no answers on Meta make me feel strangely uneasy.

Comment: Actually, each site's meta is monitored so we should eventually get an answer here.

Comment: Didn't find much useful on my brief skims through SE Meta. Will look at it in more detail to see if something useful comes about.

Comment: @Kit's correct - it's perfectly fine to ask stuff like this here. For feature-requests that aren't SharePoint-specific, you might not get a lot of attention from other users, but we do try to get through all of them sooner or later.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't really want to create an account on a separate web site for the sole purpose of having a picture to assocaite with my account.

Then don't. I rather like the image Gravatar generates for you based on a hash of your email address... Think of it as The PirateEric flag.

We use Gravatar because it works, it's (usually) fast, and **it's orthogonal to whatever other services you might be using for authentication**. Sure, *you* might find it convenient if we dragged your Google profile image onto the site - but plenty of others would find it a shocking breech of privacy... Same as if we exposed the *name* you use on Google, or your circles, or used the top post in your stream as your bio text.

Beyond that... Stack Exchange allows you to associate as many different credentials as you care to. If you want to have your Facebook, Google, Yahoo! and LiveJournal accounts all associated with your profile here, you're free to do so. If we started exposing personal information from them, which one "wins"? Does your Facebook picture trump your Google photo?  Do we use the LJ picture of you with your family, or the AOL picture of you passed out drunk with "geeklord" scrawled with a Sharpie on your forehead?

These are decisions we don't have to make, and problems you don't have to worry about, all because we place the choice of user name and picture completely within your hands.